# Wordpress shortcode doesn't working on HomePage

Tags: shortcode, homepage

What I want to do is make my Home Page. I can do it this way:

1. Create a page and insert my gallery from plugin with that code `[wonderplugin_gridgallery id=1]`
2. Set that page as HomePage.

BUT THAT IS NOT WORKING. When I add this code `[wonderplugin_gridgallery id=1]` to my page, I can see only code… The same doesn't work `<?php echo do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_gridgallery id=1]'); ?>` (hidden).

How to fix it? I don't know how to find the file to fix in FTP. Themes Virtue.

I hope you understand what I am writing about. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is code for a plugin make sure you have plugin added and activated

Comment: @Pratikbhatt, Yes activated. In file front-page.php it's written there `<?php $post_id_286 = get_post( 286 ); echo $post_id_286->post_content; ?>` this is for the main page (homepage). It turned out there does not work shortcode. The post works, the main page is not. You understand?

Comment: Your theme should output content with `the_content()` function, the attached filters are what properly process the output to make shortcodes work.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what post editor you are using:

- **Classic** - make sure to switch the editor to "Text" instead of "Visual". The latter will output anything you write in a form of text, while the first one will process the shortcode.
- **Gutenberg** - find a plus sign in the top-left area of your WordPress dashboard and add a "Shortcode" block.

If you add the shortcode manually to the file, make sure it's before the closing PHP tag: **?>**

Comment: in file only `<?php $post_id_286 = get_post( 286 ); echo $post_id_286->post_content; ?>`, but the shortcode `<?php echo do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_gridgallery id=1]'); ?>` i don't know where to insert tell me please. And Classic and Gutenberg do the same (add a "Shortcode" block) - does not work i can see only code (text). The post works, the main page is not. You understand? I'm writing above comments by another author. I hope you have already read.

Comment: Are you sure you are viewing this particular file on your WordPress website? Is the post #286 displayed there?
If you add the following code before closing PHP tag in front-page.php file, can you see any new content?
`var_dump($post_id_286)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following code in your template:

```
<?php $post_id_286 = get_post( 286 ); echo $post_id_286->post_content; ?>
```

then you should can the `do_shortcode` function to process shortcodes. Do it like this:

```
<?php $post_id_286 = get_post( 286 ); echo do_shortcode($post_id_286->post_content); ?>
```

This helped in my case. Hope it will help you too.